# Convert from 'YYYYMMDD' format to to SQL Datetime2

Tags: sql-server, string, ssis, datetime2

I have an issue concerning conversion in SSIS.
I'm trying to convert StartDATE from DT_WSTR to Datetime2 (for SQL Server)

My  date originaly looks like this 20140804 but I need  to  convert it to  Datetime2  in such format  2014-08-04 00:00:00.0000000.

What I've done earlier with the StartDATE Column is:

RTRIM(DATSTHYRA)

Since I need to remove blank spaces...

I figured I can use the already Derived Column and add a new expression to convert it to Datetime2 but I'm running into issues and can't really find a topic online that covers my issue.

Comment: It's easier to make the conversion in your SQL statement. The `YYYYMMDD` format can be converted to DATE or DATETIME directly, without localization issues. You could use `cast('20140804' as datetime2) `

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single step. 
Add Derived Column transformation - transform your YYYYMMDD string to YYYY-MM-DD with SUBSTRING functions and then - cast to DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 with scale needed. This would yield an expression like

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2, 7)(SUBSTRING([StartDATE],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([StartDATE],5,2)  
 + "-" + SUBSTRING([StartDATE],7,2))
```

Then configure Error Output on this Derived Column transformation to capture and handle conversion errors.

Comment: The unseparated date format is unambiguous and can be converted to date or datetime directly.  This code though is culture specific and can fail.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, string to be casted to SSIS Datetime has to be in format YYYY-HH-MM hh:mm:ss.nnn. From my experience, it is Culture neutral and does not depend on Server locale.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS, you can use data conversion transformation, the data type mapping is `database timestamp with precision`in SSIS is for `datetime2` in SQL Server.